# Discord js music bot doesn't play music

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make a music function for my discord bot. To be honest, I got the code from a YouTube video, but it does not work for me. There is no error or something, it just doesn't play the music. Could someone help?

```js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

bot.on('message', async (msg) => {
 if (msg.author.bot) return;
 if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

 const args = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');

 if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}play`)) {
  const voiceChannel = msg.member.voice.channel;
  if (!voiceChannel)
   return msg.channel.send('You need to be in a voice channel.');
  const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(msg.client.user);
  if (!permissions.has('CONNECT'))
   return msg.channel.send(
    "I don't have permissions to connect to a voice channel. help."
   );
  if (!permissions.has('SPEAK'))
   return msg.channel.send(
    "I don't have permissions to speak in a voice channel"
   );

  try {
   var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
  } catch (error) {
   return msg.channel.send(
    `There was an error connecting to the voice channel ${error}`
   );
  }

  const dispatcher = connection
   .play(ytdl(args[1]))
   .on('finish', () => {
    voiceChannel.leave();
   })
   .on('error', (error) => {
    msg.channel.send('There was an error: ' + error);
   });
  dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(5 / 5);
 } else if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}stop`)) {
  if (!msg.member.voice.channel)
   return msg.channel.send('You need to be in a voice channel to stop the bot');
  msg.member.voice.channel.leave();
  return undefined;
 }
});
```

Comment: Do you have `ffmpeg-static` and `@discordjs/opus` installed?

Comment: yes. I have installed it but still doesn't work

Comment: oh wait no. @Jakye when I try to install @discordjs/opus, there is an error:
TypeError: options.callback is not a function